# Makikng Alt + h switch to the left pane in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm trying to make `Alt-h` switch to the left pane in tmux. The following does not work:

```
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
```

Pressing `Alt-h` in `cat` generates the following in my terminal:

```
$ cat
^[h
```

That is, it looks like `Alt` generates `^[` in my terminal. So, in in tmux, I have also tried the following binding:

```
bind -n ^[h select-pane -L
```

I have made "^[" both a literal two character string (i.e., "^" + "[") as well as the special "^[" character you can access in vim. Neither work.

How to solve this problem?